# Find Position in a Film/Video by a Frame

Tags: video

Is there an application or online service that is able to find a position (either as a frame number or time from film beginning) in a film by a frame from that film, represented as standalone picture (even if that picture was converted, resized, cropped, etc.)?

Comment: If you leave out the cropped scenario,  then ffmpeg could do this using a combination of the blend and blackdetect filters

Comment: What do you mean by 'leave out the cropped scenario'?

Comment: Looks possible for uncropped images

Comment: But if I know position (X,Y) of the cropped image in the frame, then I can crop entire film, like the frame was cropped) and make the procedure?

Comment: What maximum divergence between the image and actual frame in the film, with which the input data can be processed successfully?

Comment: e.g. cmd `ffmpeg-in.mp4 -loop 1 -i croppedframe.jpg -an -filter_complex "[0]crop=w:h:x:y[a];[1][a]blend=difference,blackframe=90:32" -f null -` This will match a movie frame if at least 90% of the pixels have a difference in value of less than 32 with the image. Any such matching frames will have their timestamps shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -loop 1 -i croppedframe.jpg -an -filter_complex "[0]crop=w:h:x:y[a];[1][a]blend=difference,blackframe=90:32" -f null -
```

This will match a movie frame if at least 90% of the pixels have a difference in value of less than 32 with the image. Any such matching frames will have their timestamps shown